# Dual boot. Install 2nd OS on separate drive

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive

I currently have Kubuntu running on a large SATA drive. I am considering setting up KXStudio to dual boot. Rather than messing up my current partitions I am thinking of adding an old IDE drive and installing KXStudio there. I'll probably share the swap and data partitions.

Any potential pitfalls with this?

I've not dual-booted multiple Linuxes before. Is KXStudio likely to set up GRUB for me?

Comment: If KXStudio doesn't set up GRUB you can always install grub from the Ubuntu live CD

Comment: sudo update-grub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**KXStudio**

- Is based on Ubuntu and uses
  the Ubiquity installer which should
  detect any previous Ubuntu
  installations and add them to GRUB
- The only pitfall if any is the fact
  that it will be on an IDE drive so
  file transfers and the like might be
  a bit sluggish

Hope this helps

Comment: Well it worked out a bit easier than I expected. I thought re-partitioning the big drive would be tricky, but KX let me resize one to make room, so didn't use other drive. Not getting GRUB menu yet, so need to look into that. Still using Kubuntu for now. Thx

Comment: Where did you install grub to? If you put it on the root of the second drive, you will need to press the key your BIOS uses to change boot device (most newer computers use F12) and tell it to boot from the second hard drive.

Comment: I'm not sure where grub went. I did sudo update-grub from Kubuntu and now get the menu.

Comment: KDE has an Elitist "personality" doesn't like to share with any thing :)