# Can I have a computer with 2 physical HDs, & Dual boot option, one for Windows & one for Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, installation, dual-boot, hard-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dual boot. Install 2nd OS on separate drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28570/dual-boot-install-2nd-os-on-separate-drive)

What I would like to do is buy 2 HDs. Then I can have one formatted for Ubuntu 12.04 and install Windows XP Pro SP1 on the other HD for which I have the original installation CD. Then I would like to have a dual boot option so that when I power up the computer, I can choose whether to use Windows XP or Ubuntu.

Is this possible? If so, how would I do it, that is, arrange it so a dual boot option presents itself on power up.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DualBoot/Windows

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this easily.

The easiest way is to first install Windows on one drive and get it working.  Then, install Ubuntu with that drive present but choose the second hard drive (probably sdb), using the entire drive as one partition (sdb1).  The install will automatically detect the Windows OS on the first drive (sda), and create a dual-boot menu (using GRUB).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I am not familiar with sdb or GRUB but I'm sure a little google searching will turn up some answers. Thanks again.

Comment: GRUB is the bootloader that lives in the boot record of the bootable disk.  And I disks are referenced by codes such as /dev/sda (1st disk), /dev/sdb (2nd), /dev/sdg for USB, /dev/sr0 for CD, and various other weird names.  I should have used the full /dev/sdb, etc.  They are all accessed as raw data in the /dev directory, and mounted from there along with a "template" that describes the organization.  Makes for interesting reading. :)